# Pipes in Unix. Error while implementing an example

Tags: linux, unix, system

I am new to Unix and Linux. I am trying an example from a book "System Programming with C and Unix" by Adam Hoover, Pg 159-162. I am using Linux Ubuntu.

I want to pipe two C codes (summer | bingo ).

summer.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int x,s;
   s =0 ;
   while(1)
   {
      printf("#?");
      scanf("%d",&x);
      if (x == 0)
        break;
      s = s +x;
     printf("sum = %d\n",s);    
   }
}
```

bingo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
   char s[80];
   while(1)
   {
      scanf("%s",s);
      if ( strcmp(s,"sum=5") == 0 )
      {
          printf("Bingo!\n");
      }
      else if( strcmp(s,"sum=12") == 0)
      {
          break;
      } 
   }
}
```

In Linux terminal I follow the commands.

1. gcc -o summer summer.c
2. gcc -o bingo bingo.c
3. summer | bingo

I am unable to do it, it gives an error.

"The program 'summer' is currently not installed.

You can install it by typing:

sudo apt install chiark-utils-bin

No command 'bingo' found, did you mean:

Command 'bing' from package 'bing' (universe)

Command 'bino' from package 'bino' (universe)

bingo: command not found"

summer and bingo files are working using **./summer** and **./bingo**

but, **./summer| bingo** doesn't works.

I have tried to use "<" standard In or ">" standard out.
These work out perfectly. **but " | " gives an error**.

Any help will be very useful in learning UNIX.

Comment: You need `./` for both: `./summer | ./bingo`

Comment: If that book tells you to use `void main()`, please find a better book. `int main(void)` is correct. It's a fairly minor point, but it indicates that the author doesn't know C very well, and the book could contain other more serious errors. If the book *doesn't* suggest `void main()`, why did you decide to use it yourself?

Comment: Update: I downloaded a free sample of the Kindle edition of the book. There's only one C program shown in the sample. It uses `main()`, which isn't *quite* as bad as `void main()`, but it still doesn't indicate that the author knows C very well.

Comment: @KeithThompson void main () was my mistake, will avoid using it, int main(void) it makes much better sense.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Explicitly specify the path to **both** commands

```
./summer | ./bingo
```

Option 2: Add the current path to the PATH so they will be found. On `bash`, you could execute

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(pwd)"
summer | bingo
```

Note that adding "." to the PATH isn't the safest thing to do, instead actually specify the path containing `summer` and `bingo` or use `pwd` to add the current folder explicitly.

Comment: Just use option 1. Get into the habit of typing `./` in front of any command that's in the current directory. (There could be another `summer` or `bingo` command elsewhere in `$PATH`. `test` vs. `./test` is a common pitfall that you can easily void by using `./` when you run a local command.)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The reason your Bash shell can't find the program `summer` is because your working directory isn't on the path.

Bash uses the variable `PATH` to locate programs. You can see what your path looks like by executing `echo $PATH` in your shell. It will look something like:

```
user@host:/$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

When you enter a command, Bash checks the path and looks in the included locations (i.e. `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin`) for the program. It doesn't look anywhere else (like your current directory) so if the program can't be found, the shell just returns an error.

If you want to execute a program in a location that isn't on your path, you need to exlpicitly provide the full path to the program. This might be:

```
/path/to/your/working/directory/summer
```

In Linux every directory contains a `.` which refers to itself. You can use this:

```
./summer
```

And the `.` is expanded to the full path of the current directory.

Sometimes you might want to add a location to your path, say `/opt/bin` or `/home/user/bin` but I wouldn't add `.`, that's a bit heavy handed. Just refer to programs in your current directory explicitly like `./program`.